# Jech's proof of ${|\omega_\alpha|}^2 = |\omega_\alpha|$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Page 31 of Jech's "Set Theory" (3rd edition), for the proof of theorem 3.5:

> [...] let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that $\Gamma(\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha ) \neq \omega_\alpha$.
>
> Let $\beta, \gamma < \omega_\alpha$ be such that $\Gamma(\beta,\gamma) = \omega_\alpha$.
>
> Pick $\delta < \omega_\alpha$ such that $\delta > \beta$ and $\delta > \gamma$

where $\Gamma$ is a one-to-one mapping of $Ord^2$ onto $Ord$ defined by letting $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ be the order type of the set $\{(\xi, \eta) : (\xi, \eta) < (\alpha, \beta)\}$ in the canonical well-ordering of $Ord^2$.

I don't see why we can necessarily find $\beta$ and $\gamma$ *both* strictly inferior to $\omega_\alpha$, such that $\Gamma(\beta,\gamma)=\omega_\alpha$.

Why couldn't one of them, say $\beta$, be equal to $\omega_\alpha$, and only the other one strictly inferior to it?

Comment: What is the definition of $\Gamma$?

Comment: It is because the function $\gamma(\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)$ is increasing, so $\gamma(\omega_1)\geq\omega_1$. This inequality allow us to take an initial segment of $\omega_1\times\omega_1$ with order type $\omega_1$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I edited my question to precise that. Thanks.

By the way, it seems that the notation $\Gamma(\alpha \times \alpha)$ is thus a malapropism for $\Gamma(\alpha, \alpha)$, but this leaves my question intact.

Comment: @almaus I think that's part of your problem.. it is not a malapropism. It means the image of the set $\alpha\times\alpha$ under the function $\Gamma.$

Comment: @Gödel But then why do you necessarily have such an initial segment $\beta\times\gamma$ with *both* $\beta < \omega_\alpha$ and $\gamma < \omega_\alpha$?

Why not just either?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think you found what I missed!! Thanks, I'll read everything again with this in mind.

Yes I confirm, that's obvious now thanks to you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward induction argument shows that $\Gamma(\beta\times\beta)$ is an ordinal $\ge \beta$ for all $\beta,$ so if $\omega_\alpha\ne \Gamma(\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha)$, this means $\omega_\alpha\in \Gamma(\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha),$ which means precisely that there are $\beta,\gamma < \omega_\alpha$ with $\Gamma(\beta,\gamma)=\omega_\alpha.$